# Create thinking emoji from the word thinking

Tags: rust, emoji

I looked at https://docs.rs/emojis/0.1.1/emojis/struct.Emoji.html and saw the code

```
let thinking = emojis::lookup("").unwrap();
assert_eq!(thinking.shortcode().unwrap(), "thinking");
```

I looked through the documentation quickly. Is there a way to revere the process of lookup? That is, can I get the nice thinking character from something like

```
let mut s : char = emojis::character_from_shortcode(":thinking:");
```

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Please don't post answers in the comments.

Comment: @orlp This question is as basic as looking into the docs. I don't even think it's suitable for StackOverflow as such

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Sure but you can still post answers in the answers section and/or vote to close the question.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov As long as it is not a duplicate it is suitable for SO, but deserves a downvote for lack of research.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation page](https://docs.rs/emojis/latest/emojis/index.html) of `emojis` crate, you can use [`emojis::get_by_shortcode`](https://docs.rs/emojis/latest/emojis/fn.get_by_shortcode.html) function.

> pub fn get_by_shortcode(s: &str) -> Option<&'static Emoji>

One example they give is:

```
let rocket = emojis::get_by_shortcode("rocket").unwrap();
assert_eq!(rocket, "");
```

Comment: Thanks. I am surprised that I missed that.